# __eds__ Extended Data Space qualifier syntax

Tags: c, xc16

I am using compiler XC16 from Microchip.
Are the following code lines equivalent?

```
__eds__ __attribute__((eds)) short fr[N_WAVE];

__eds__ short fr[N_WAVE] __attribute__((eds));
```

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Does the compiler complain?

Comment: @Matt No, it does not complain, but I am not sure if both lines do exactly the same actions...